# External component Knockout and Require

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm just learning knockout and I need some help. My menucomponent won't show up (i.e. it should say "Boo ya ka sha"). In chrome (under the scripts inspector) I can see that htmlString is set properly (i.e. to the contents of components/menu.html). Help, please.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
  <script data-main="js/app" src="js/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <menucomponent></menucomponent>
</body>
</html>
```

js/app.js

```
requirejs.config({
  "baseUrl": "js",
  "paths": {
    "app": "app",
    "jquery": "jquery-2.2.3",
    "knockout":"knockout-3.4.0",
    "main": "main",
    "menu": "../components/menu",
    "text": "require-text"
  }
});
// make a component called menucomponent
require(['knockout'], function(ko) {
  ko.components.register('menucomponent', {require: 'menu'});
});
// Load the main app module to start the app
requirejs(["main"]);
```

components/menu.js

```
define(['knockout','text!./menu.html'], function(ko, htmlString) {
  function menuViewModel() {
    this.myMessage = ko.observable("Boo ya ka sha");
  }
  return { viewModel: menuViewModel,
           template: htmlString
         };
});
```

components/menu.html

```
<div data-bind='text: myMessage'></div>
```

Comment: Can you please check whether there are any console errors too?

Comment: There are no console errors/warnings in Chrome

Comment: I have also tried (without success) registering the component like so (in js/app.js) require(['knockout', 'menu'], function(ko,menuComponent) { ko.components.register('menucomponent', menuComponent); });

Answer (score 0):

Knockout supports amd registration for viewmodel only, so try this:

In js/app.js, change your component registration to:

```
require(['knockout','text!./menu.html'], function(ko, htmlString) {
  ko.components.register('menucomponent', {
     viewModel: { require: 'menu'},
     template: htmlString
  });
```

and change components/menu.js to:

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {
  function menuViewModel() {
     this.myMessage = ko.observable("Boo ya ka sha");
  }
  return menuViewModel;
});
```